# NIntegrate evaluates a clearly non-zero integral to be zero. The integrand is a set of data points morphed into a distribution

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integration, distribution

I have a list of data points that are to represent a probability distribution. I need to integrate over this distribution. However since I didn't have a function and I only had a set of data points, I came up with the following code to represent the probability distribution:

```
dList1 = Import["Z-1.txt", "Table"];
dList2 = Import["Z_over-1.txt", "Table"];

dDist[X_,sym_] := (

  dList = 0;

  If[sym,
    dList = dList1;
  ,
    dList = dList2;
  ];

  val = 0;

  If[Abs[X] < Pi,
    i = 2;
    While[dList[[i]][[1]] < X, i++];

    width = dList[[i]][[1]] - dList[[i-1]][[1]];

    difX = dList[[i]][[1]] - X;
    difY = dList[[i]][[2]] - dList[[i-1]][[2]];

    val = dList[[i-1]][[2]] + (1-(difX/width)) difY;
  ];

  Return[val];
);
```

where the set of data points are in the text files.

Performing the following command:

```
Plot[dDist[x, True], {x, -1, 1}]
```

gives this:

[image: Plot[dDist[x, True], {x, -1, 1}]]

Whereas, performing this:

```
NIntegrate[dDist[x, True], {x, -1, 1}]
```

evaluates to zero, along with this warning:
[image: Warning]

I have tried increasing MinRecursion to no avail. I'm not sure what to do and would be open to any suggestions, including modifying the dDist function.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HotLicks, the problem is not a mathematical one. The math is fine, mathematica is calculating it wrong for some reason.

Comment: It would help a lot to have even a minimal set of data you're using. In general, you might try to interpolate your point before the integration or use `EmpiricalDistribution`.

Answer (score 0):

Not having your data to play with, I'd suggest using the table(s) to create Piecewise functions separated at the disontinuities. NIntegrate should handle those with no problem.